# Unable to download or update anything from both anaconda and pip on mac os

Tags: python, pip, conda, http-error

Suddenly I'm unable to download or update anything  from both anaconda and pip on mac os.
When I'm trying to download or update from anaconda I get the following error:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/soumith/osx-64/current_repodata.json

when trying to install something trough pip I get the following errors and warnings:

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->requests-html->facebook-scraper) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->requests-html->facebook-scraper)

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Can anyone pls help?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is telling you that the SSL module is missing or not working.  You may need to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks! How can I reinstall it?

Comment: I've tried with brew and still have the same problem

Comment: maybe you have to instal C/C++ library [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)

Comment: Thanks! how? I've dowloaded it, what now?

Comment: This may not be much help, but I started experiencing exactly the same issue at about the same time for no apparent reason. I think we will have to find another forum to get this looked into.